# Concatenating Pandas data frame without removing row names

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2`. They are created with the following codes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Probe1", "Gene1", 3,11], 
                    ["Probe1", "Gene2", 6,10],
                    ["Probe2","Gene2", 13,18]], 
        columns=['probe', 'gene', 'Sample1', "Sample2"]).set_index(['probe', 'gene'])
df1.columns.names = ['Sample']
# Note that number of samples can be more than two


df2 = df1.copy()
df2[df2>0] = 1.00
```

So it looks like this:

```
In [74]: df1
Out[74]:
Sample        Sample1  Sample2
probe  gene
Probe1 Gene1        3       11
       Gene2        6       10
Probe2 Gene2       13       18

In [75]: df2
Out[75]:
Sample        Sample1  Sample2
probe  gene
Probe1 Gene1        1        1
       Gene2        1        1
Probe2 Gene2        1        1
```

What I want to do is to concatenate these two data frame so that in the end it will write into CSV file that looks like this:

```
PROBE  GENE      SMPL1    SMPL2 PROBE  GENE      SMPL1    SMPL2
Probe1 Gene1        3       11  Probe1 Gene1      1        1
Probe1 Gene2        6       10  Probe1 Gene2      1        1
Probe2 Gene2       13       18  Probe2 Gene2      1        1
```

I'm stuck with this:`pd.concat(ndf,axis=1)`

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reseting the index should give you what you want.

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(),df2.reset_index()],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Sample   probe   gene  Sample1  Sample2   probe   gene  Sample1  Sample2

0       Probe1  Gene1        3       11  Probe1  Gene1        1        1
1       Probe1  Gene2        6       10  Probe1  Gene2        1        1
2       Probe2  Gene2       13       18  Probe2  Gene2        1        1
```

Comment: No it doesn't! I cannot reproduce your result.

Comment: @pdubois Whoops!  Edited.

Answer (score 2):

User `join` and then `reset_index`:

```
In [1422]: df1
Out[1422]: 
Sample        Sample1  Sample2
probe  gene                   
Probe1 Gene1        3       11
       Gene2        6       10
Probe2 Gene2       13       18

In [1423]: df2
Out[1423]: 
Sample        Sample1  Sample2
probe  gene                   
Probe1 Gene1        1        1
       Gene2        1        1
Probe2 Gene2        1        1
```

Output:

```
In [1424]: df1.join(df2, rsuffix='df2').reset_index()
Out[1424]: 
Sample   probe   gene  Sample1  Sample2  Sample1df2  Sample2df2
0       Probe1  Gene1        3       11           1           1
1       Probe1  Gene2        6       10           1           1
2       Probe2  Gene2       13       18           1           1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I generalize to 4 samples:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Probe1", "Gene1", 3,11,30,100], 
                   ["Probe1", "Gene2", 6,10,100,23],
                   ["Probe2","Gene2", 13,18,20,77]], 
        columns=['probe', 'gene', 'Sample1', "Sample2","Sample3","Sample4"]).set_index(['probe', 'gene'])
df1.columns.names = ['Sample']


df2 = df1.copy()
df2[df2>0] = 1.00
ndf = [df1,df2]
fdf = pd.concat(ndf,axis=1)
fdf.reset_index(inplace=True)

ins1 = df1.shape[1]+2
ins2 = ins1 + 1
print ins1,ins2
fdf.insert(ins1,'probe2',fdf['probe'])
fdf.insert(ins2,'gene2',fdf['gene'])
fdf
```

gives

```
In [149]: fdf
Out[149]:
Sample   probe   gene  Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4  probe2  gene2  \
0       Probe1  Gene1        3       11       30      100  Probe1  Gene1
1       Probe1  Gene2        6       10      100       23  Probe1  Gene2
2       Probe2  Gene2       13       18       20       77  Probe2  Gene2

Sample  Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4
0             1        1        1        1
1             1        1        1        1
2             1        1        1        1
```